# In Diablo 3, what legendary or set armour/weapons are actually account bound?

Tags: diablo-iii

On the console version of Diablo 3 (Xbox One), what type of items are not tradable?  I recently made a items from a sets and stand-alone legendary weapons/armour pieces.

For example, [Bom's Impunity](https://us.diablo3.blizzard.com/en-gb/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/borns-impunity). On the Blizzard online game guide it says that this item is **account bound**. However, I was able to craft this for a friend. I dropped it and he was able to pick it up. I'm a bit confused by this.

##### How can I know what items are actually account bound, or not?

I don't want to waste materials making items he won't be able to use.
Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed to add another, more specific tag. Please edit it as necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if crafted legendary also affected by this, but any legendary/set items that's picked up with your party (you+up to 3 people) are able to trade for 1 hour, so that players can trade legendary/set items each other. If anyone can confirm that crafted legendary/set also get affected by this mechanic, feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Consoles, you can trade with online or system-linked players through the 'party' menu  by selecting 'offer item' or 'offer gold' to indicate what you'd like to exchange.

[Can't Trade in Diablo III](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/82954)

Comment: Thank you - so is this the same mechanic that happens by dropping a crafted item and a friend picking it up. I didn't use the party menu. Does this work for all crafted items?

Comment: It seems some old crafted legendary/set items (from original D3, before Reaper of Souls) can be traded or given to other players who were in the game when the item was crafted, like the same 2 hours rule for any legendary items dropped during co-op play.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. That makes sense. :)